# Unable to suspend to RAM because of unreachable NFS server

Tags: networking, kubuntu, suspend, nfs

With my Kubuntu 16.04 system, I am no longer able to suspend to RAM. This worked ever since and stopped working just a few weeks ago. Very annoying. I guess some update messed it up.

**Update**: Problem remains even after installing 18.04.1 from the scratch. Still not able to suspend.

Trying to suspend via KDE menue, KDE stops and I watch the mouse pointer on a black screen forever. Switching to console, syslog tells me that

1. NetworkManager goes to sleep,
2. whoopsie comes up, but cannot reach daisy.ubuntu.com.
3. systemd reaches target Sleep and starts Suspend, reaches Timers, Paths, Sockets, Basic System and Default.
4. kernel tries to sync filesystems which leads to
5. nfs server not responding.
6. ksmserver complains about being blocked for more than 120 seconds.

Can anybody help me out? In case I missed something, the syslog follows.

```
avahi-daemon[972]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.2.30 on enp3s0.
avahi-daemon[972]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.2.30.
avahi-daemon[972]: Interface enp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
dnsmasq[1091]: vorgelagerte Server von DBus gesetzt
dbus[956]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher
.service'
NetworkManager[961]: <info>  [1532090369.8150] device (enp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [30 1
0 37]
systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
dbus[956]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [enp3s0]: new request (1 scripts)
nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [enp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
NetworkManager[961]: <info>  [1532090369.8403] device (enp3s0): link disconnected
whoopsie[1250]: [14:39:34] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
whoopsie[1250]: [14:39:34] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
acpid: client 1386[0:0] has disconnected
systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
systemd-sleep[9497]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
systemd-sleep[9498]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
systemd-sleep[9497]: Suspending system...
kernel: [17527.365778] PM: suspend entry (deep)
org.kde.KScreen[2039]: kscreen: Primary output changed from KScreen::Output(Id: 448 , Name: "HDMI-0" ) ( "HDMI-0" ) to KScreen::O
org.kde.KScreen[2039]: kscreen: Primary output changed from KScreen::Output(Id: 448 , Name: "HDMI-0" ) ( "HDMI-0" ) to KScreen::Output(Id: 448 , Name: "HDMI-0" ) ( "HDMI-0" )
org.kde.KScreen[2039]: message repeated 3 times: [ kscreen: Primary output changed from KScreen::Output(Id: 448 , Name: "HDMI-0" ) ( "HDMI-0" ) to KScreen::Output(Id: 448 , Name: "HDMI-0" ) ( "HDMI-0" )]
systemd[9560]: Reached target Timers.
systemd[9560]: Reached target Paths.
systemd[9560]: Reached target Sockets.
systemd[9560]: Reached target Basic System.
systemd[9560]: Reached target Default.
systemd[9560]: Startup finished in 16ms.
systemd[1]: Requested transaction contradicts existing jobs: Transaction is destructive.
kernel: [17527.365780] PM: Syncing filesystems ... 
kernel: [17704.242663] nfs: server centaurus not responding, still trying
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it was, it vanished with the updates deployed during the last 8 months. The problem no longer exists.