# Suspend with active NFS connection fails

Tags: network-manager, suspend, nfs

With my Ubuntu server upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 and Kubuntu client upgrade from 20.04 to 21.04, I can no longer suspend my client. Home directory is on NFS, so unmounting if NetworkManager dispatches a pre-down signal with `umount --verbose --lazy --all --types nfs,nfs4,cifs` (as suggested [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/NetworkManager/Dispatcher/) on German Ubuntuusers) fails as expected.

Trouble is, almost everything shuts down as expected, but after

```
Mar 18 09:22:07 kernel: [ 1736.863060] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
Mar 18 09:22:17 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Mar 18 09:22:32 whoopsie[1170]: [09:22:32] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Mar 18 09:22:37 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Mar 18 09:22:37 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Mar 18 09:22:37 systemd-sleep[7395]: Suspending system...
Mar 18 09:22:37 kernel: [ 1767.068992] PM: suspend entry (deep)
```

I get, after waiting 2 minutes, the infamous `NFS server not responding, still trying`.

Everything works as expected without NFS directories mounted and surpisingly, even with a directory mounted and an active `tail -f` on a NFS file works. Problem occurs only if my NFS user is logged on.

I had a [similar problem in 2018](https://askubuntu.com/q/1057964/349335) which just vanished after some time.

Could anybody help me out with that? What is the intended procedure if you have your homedir on NFS and would like to suspend the system?

**Update**

Switched to console and force-unmounted the NFS directories after `PM: suspend entry (deep)`. The system immediately suspended.

After resuming, `mount --all` brought back the NFS directories and I could resume the interactive session without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Autofs is a system that automatically mounts and unmounts your shares, one type could be nfs, as you access them and dismounts them when not needed anymore. Afaik autofs can also handle suspend.

I could write a long howto here or simply link to someone who already did it.

https://gist.github.com/vegaasen/06d75cc19f108380a909d3b06a2aab7a